# Chrome Extension Execute Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I'm writing a chrome extension and trying to execute a script on my page.

My manifest.json includes:

```
 "permissions": ["tabs"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*"],
            "js": ["js/jquery.js", "js/content.js"]
        }
    ]
```

And on my content.js page I have:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( null, {code:"document.write('hello world')"},
    function(results){ console.log(results); } );
```

According to google's documentation, passing a null parameter has it refer to the active tab and I can then pass the javascript as a json object, which I am. However... no result? Any advice? Ideally, I'd like to to change document.write to a window command to get the the user's highlighted text.

Answer (score 0):

You must have permissions for injecting script in a webpage...
for example

`"permissions": [  "http://stackoverflow.com/"]`

If you like to inject in all web pages you should specify:

`"permissions": [
  "<all_urls>", ].`